# How to display twilio SMS messages on a squarespace page

Tags: twilio, sms, squarespace

I'm creating a portfolio sight and I would like people to be able to text feedback to the sight directly. Example: Co-worker wants to leave a review they text "blah blah" to my Twilio phone number and it shows up in a block on my square space page. Is that possible? Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thank you in advance :)

I'm still in the searching documents stage. All the documents I can find relate to sending SMS messages. I want to receive and display SMS messages on my website (I don't want to send SMSs).

Thank you again:)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. After they text your Twilio number, you can grab the input of their message with something like (Python example):

```
user_input = request.values.get('Body', None)
```

Once you have the input, you can handle it any way you'd like. In your case, you'd want to pass the input to your rendering language (HTML) so it shows on your website.